# Is name still a line item when trying to make stripe payments in Angular apps?

Tags: angular, stripe-payments

I am trying to follow a tutorial that adds Stripe to an Angular app.

The tutorial video shows the documentation on Stripe's official website on how to create a session.

Inside the object used to create a session, there are a number of line items.

The line items in the tutorial video are `name`, `description`, `amount`, `currency`.

I've followed the tutorial perfectly so far, but now am getting this error message:

```
Purchasing course with id:  Z9CicdZalK023hJOJu7A
{
  payment_method_types: [ 'card' ],
  success_url: 'http://localhost:4200/stripe-checkout/?purchaseRe
  cancel_url: 'http://localhost:4200/stripe-checkout/?purchaseRes
  line_items: [ { name: '', description: '', amount: 1500, curren
}
Unexpected error occurred while purchasing course:  StripeInvalidems[0][name]'. We assume empty values are an attempt to unset a pet. You should remove 'line_items[0][name]' from your request
```

I looked at the latest documentation myself [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=node). The only line items mentioned here are price & quantity, so I am wondering is `name` no longer used as a line item, & thus the reason I am getting the error.

Can someone please advise as to whether or not this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To improve the integration logic, Stripe released a new API called `Price` which lets you define your product catalog in Stripe and then reference those directly in Checkout. The idea is that you can create Products and Prices in the Dashboard easily and then reference a given Price id `price_123456` when creating your Checkout `Session` in the API. This is covered in details here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/accept-a-payment

Your tutorial uses a legacy integration path where you would pass price details directly in the API. This relied on sending `name`, `amount` and such inside `line_items`. This integration path should still work though it's considered deprecated. The error you are getting here is simply that you are passing an empty string for `name` which is not allowed in the API. You just have to change your code to pass a non-empty string for `name` and it should just work.

I would encourage you to tweak the code though to pass `price: 'price_123'` though instead. You can also reach out to the author of the tutorial to ask them to update their code to use the latest integration path.

Comment: Is it still possible to create `line_items` as in the legacy code? What if I don't want to create a product on the Stripe dashboard?

Comment: @Simone You shouldn't use a deprecated method to build a new integration no. You should create product in the Dashboard or in the API because it'll be a way more powerful experience for you. But otherwise you can always create a Price and Product inline with `price_data` and `product_data` https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items-price_data